# Formatting Json Response string to date in lightning component

Tags: lightning-aura-components, json

I am working on a requirement for making API call getting the response and showing it on lightning component.

My Json responce for one of the field is

```
nextPeriodEndDate=20170406.
```

I need to make it as `2017-04-06`

My `Json2APEX` class parsing the field as string .

The original response from API is below

```
"accounts": [{
                  "amount": 250,
                  "nextPeriodEndDate": "20170406",
                  "contractDate": "20170131",
                  "contractStartDate": "20170106",
                  "contractEndDate": "20170406",
                  "currentPeriodStartDate": "20170106",
                  "currentPeriodEndDate": "20170406",
                  "contractDuration": "00000300",
                  "contractRate": 0.7,
                  "baseInterestRate": 0,
                  "annualInterestRate": 0.7,
                  "interestRateProposed": 0.7,
                  "grossInterestAmount": 0.43,
                  "currentPeriodGrossInterest": 0.43
    }]
```

After parsing it with [JSON2Apex](https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/) the class is generated. The wrapper inside the `JSON2Apex` class looks like below

```
 public class Accounts {
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer amount {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String accountNumber {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String counterPartyAccountNumber {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String nextPeriodEndDate {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String contractDate {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String contractStartDate {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String contractEndDate {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String currentPeriodStartDate {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled 
    public String currentPeriodEndDate {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public String contractDuration {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public Double contractRate {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public Integer baseInterestRate {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public Double annualInterestRate {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled 
    public Double interestRateProposed {get;set;}
    @AuraEnabled 
    public Double grossInterestAmount {get;set;} 
    @AuraEnabled
    public Double currentPeriodGrossInterest {get;set;}
}
```

All the date field are interpreted as string .

Tried converting the string field date using `Date.valueOf` and `Date.parser` method in below block the

```
else if (text == 'nextPeriodEndDate') {
                        nextPeriodEndDate = parser.getText();
```

The output is like `nextPeriodEndDate=20170406-01-01 00:00:00`

The javascript for setting the column looks like below

```
        {
            type: 'date',
            fieldName: 'nextPeriodEndDate',
            label: 'Period EndDate',
            cellAttributes: { alignment: 'left' },
            typeAttributes:{year:'numeric',day:'numeric',month:'numeric'}

        },
```

Can anyone help me for converting the String `nextPeriodEndDate=20170406`  to `nextPeriodEndDate=2017-04-06`  or `nextPeriodEndDate=2017/04/06`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its more simple if you pass the miliseconds directly. You can use:

```
var dat = new Date(1469433907836);
dat.toLocaleString();
```

But if you want to pass your date as a string, you can use a function like this:

```
var n = "20170406";
var array = Array.from(n);
var newVar = '';
for (var i=0; i<array.length; i++){
    if (i === 3) {
        newVar += array[i] + "-";
    } else if (i === 5) {
        newVar += array[i] + "-";
    } else {
        newVar += array[i];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

you can use power of [substring](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_string.htm)  method to extract year, month and day separetly

> Returns a new String that begins with the character at the specified
>   zero-based startIndex and extends to the character at endIndex - 1.

---

```
String nextPeriodEndDate = '20170406';
Integer year = Integer.valueOf(nextPeriodEndDate.substring(0, 4));
Integer month = Integer.valueOf(nextPeriodEndDate.substring(4, 6));
Integer day = Integer.valueOf(nextPeriodEndDate.substring(6, 8));
System.debug('year:' + year); //2017
System.debug('month:' + month);//4
System.debug('day:' + day);//6
```

Now, having this values. you can create new `Date` instance:

```
Date nextPeriodEndDateParsed = Date.newinstance(year, month, day);
```

So now you have prepared data to be sent to lightning component